# Google Analytic Tracking using rack-google-analytic gem can not load GA.js from google-analytics.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics

I just set up this gem and pushed to heroku ok. However, I found that the generated js code can not download the follow resource

```
http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js
```

and that explained why I did not see any traffic on Google analytics site. So I tried to paste the above url into browser directly and got "site not found error"

Question:

Is the url for ga.js  changed?

or

Why couldn't I download it directly?

ps.  below is the code trying to download ga.js.

```
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is silly. I couldn't believe that google would let ppl having trouble downloading ga.js for so long.

And the culprit is really my own computer's hosts file  redirect www.google-analytics.com  to 127.0.0.1    (might have been done some internet protection software )